# PBS and specify nodes to use

Tags: grid

when you submit jobs to a PBS server, is it possible to specify the nodes that we want to use in a list?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Yes. When you use qsub, use the -l option to specify the node names. e.g.

```
qsub -l nodes=b2005+b1803+b1813
```

There's more examples in this TORQUE/PBS [manual page](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/6-0-1/help.htm#topics/torque/2-jobs/requestingRes.htm%3FTocPath%3D3%2520Submitting%2520and%2520Managing%2520Jobs%7CJob%2520Submission%7C_____3).

Comment: [manual page](http://www.clusterresources.com/torquedocs21/2.1jobsubmission.shtml#nodeExamples) broken link

Comment: [currently working link](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/4-1-3/Content/topics/2-jobs/requestingRes.htm#qsub)